# Windows Backup problems with a NAS

Tags: windows, backup, nas, drobo

I'm using the Windows 7 backup program in Windows 10 to backup multiple computers to a DROBO NAS.

The NAS always reports it has 16TB of available space, whether or not that is the actual amount available. The backup application does not know how much actual space is available and so cannot automatically prune the current backups to free space up for the new ones.

Because of this the drives are always filling up and we're having to add new drives.

Is there a way I can tell the Windows 7 backup application what its maximum storage size should be so that it can automatically manage these backups better and I won't have to keep adding drives or manually deleting old backups myself?

Comment: **1.** `Using the windows 7 backup application`... now that's funny... Sounds like you may need to make adjustments to your data backup strategy or look into other solutions potentially as well. There are many Windows native ways to delete files or directories that are older than a certain number of days i.e. batch, powershell, forfiles, and so forth. . . Check out the FREE Windows Open-Source o{[||||]];;::;;::;;:;;> https://www.urbackup.org/ as it does file backups and image backups with many options and has a flexible scheduling mechanism as well.

Comment: Is there a particular reason your DROBO reports an inaccurate value for the available space? Can this be fixed?